# Keep calculation going while loop freezes program and put a pause inbetween calculations

Tags: java

Hello i have this code where you click on several cubes to set them to dead or alive and according to a set of rules java will calculate which cells will be alive/dead after the next step.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class GameOfLife implements ActionListener{
Scanner scanner;                                                               //to      read the text file
File file;
boolean play = false;
String filename = "birth.txt";                                                 //the file that has to be read
Cell[][] cells=new Cell[10][10];                                               //array containing all the cells
JButton nextButton;
JButton playButton;
JPanel buttonPanel;
JPanel cellPanel;
GridLayout gridLayout=new GridLayout(10,10);
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
void buildit(){
    readInput();
    frame.setSize(600,700);        
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buttonPanel=new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,100));
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    nextButton=new JButton("Next generation");
    playButton=new JButton("Play");
    nextButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
    playButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
    nextButton.addActionListener(this);
    playButton.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(nextButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    frame.add(playButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    cellPanel=new JPanel();        
    cellPanel.setLayout(gridLayout);                                               //gives the panel a gridlayout
    cellPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    frame.add(cellPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  
        cells[i%10][i/10]=new Cell();                                            //i/10 will be rounded down, so it equals the rownumber
        cellPanel.add(cells[i%10][i/10]);
        cells[i%10][i/10].addMouseListener(cells[i%10][i/10]);                   //add a mouselistener to the cell
        cells[i%10][i/10].setOpaque(true);                                       //makes the backgroundcolor visible
        cells[i%10][i/10].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        cells[i%10][i/10].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));

    }    

    frame.setVisible(true);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
            if((i%10-1+j%3>=0) && (i%10-1+j%3<10) && (i/10-1+j/3>=0) && (i/10-1+j/3<10) && !(j==4)){   //exclude cells that are outside the frame (non existant) and the cell itself  
                cells[i%10][i/10].setNeighbours(cells[i%10-1+j%3][i/10-1+j/3]);           //this adds all the neighbours to the arraylist
            }
        }
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource()==nextButton){
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){ 
            cells[i%10][i/10].calculateNextState(); 
        }
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  
            cells[i%10][i/10].updateToNextState();
        }
    }
    else{if (e.getSource()==playButton) {
      play = true;
      for (int p=0; p<3;p++) {

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){ 
            cells[i%10][i/10].calculateNextState(); 
        }
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  
            cells[i%10][i/10].updateToNextState();
        }

    }

    }

    }
}

void readInput(){
    try{
        file = new File( filename);
        scanner = new Scanner( file );
        String nextGen="";                                                               //this string will contain the output
        int row=scanner.nextInt();                                                       //read the row number
        int col=scanner.nextInt();                                                       //and the column number
        Cell[][] cellen=new Cell[row][col];                                              //array containing all the cells
        for(int i=0; i<row*col; i++){
            cellen[i%row][i/col]=new Cell(); 
            if(scanner.next().equals(".")){
                cellen[i%row][i/col].setState(CellState.alive);                                     //set the state
            }
            else{
                cellen[i%row][i/col].setState(CellState.dead); 

            }

        }
        for(int i=0; i<row*col; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
                if((i%row-1+j%3>=0) && (i%row-1+j%3<row) && (i/col-1+j/3>=0) && (i/col-1+j/3<col) && !(j==4)){ 
                    cellen[i%row][i/col].setNeighbours(cellen[i%row-1+j%3][i/col-1+j/3]);            //set the neighbours
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<row*col; i++){
            cellen[i%row][i/col].calculateNextState();                                  //calculate the next state for all the cells
        }
        for(int i=0; i<row*col; i++){
            cellen[i%row][i/col].updateToNextState();                                   //update all the cells to the next state
        }
        for(int i=0; i<row; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<col; j++){
                if(cellen[i%row][i/col].getCurrentState()==CellState.alive){                             //the cell is alive if getCurrentState is true
                    nextGen+="*";
                }
                else{
                    nextGen+=".";
                }
            }
            nextGen+=System.getProperty("line.separator");                              //add an enter after each row
        }
        System.out.println(nextGen);                                                    //print the next generation to the console
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println( "Could not find or open file <"+filename+">\n"+e );         
    } 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GameOfLife().buildit();
}
}
```

My problem is that when i try to keep the calculation for an unlimited amount of times
My program freezes up as you can see in the code below

```
 else{if (e.getSource()==playButton) {
      play = true;
      for (int p=0; p<3;p++) {

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){ 
            cells[i%10][i/10].calculateNextState(); 
        }
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  
            cells[i%10][i/10].updateToNextState();
        }

    }

    }
```

I only go through the calculations 3 times however i want it to go through these an unlimited amount of times until a stop button (jet to be created) where there is a pause of 1 second between each calculation. I already tried a while loop but this just froze up my aplication
Some help with both the pause and the unlimited calculations would be greatly apriciated

Comment: You need to run your calculations on a separate thread. You should only perform UI interactions on the UI thread and do everything else that might take a while (network connections, calculations) on a background thread that updates the UI when it has something to display.

Comment: Make a Thread that has a while loop, make a boolean that triggers when the button is pressed, then in the loop, make the condition saying 'if boolean is true', then Thread.sleep for 1000 miliseconds, then stop thread. If no one has code posted for this, ill write some when i get home. On my phone right now.

EDIT: If you wanna interact with the UIThread outside of the App/Panel/Frame class, then use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { code that manipulates frame/panel } });

Comment: I would suggest that you start by reading up on threads - how to create one, how to start it, how to make it sleep, and what happens if you interrupt it while it is sleeping.  You'll need a thread for your calculations, which you'll interrupt when the user clicks the "stop" button.

Comment: Vince Emigh EDIT: the written code would be greatly apriciated

Comment: I have posted some info as an answer. Please check it out, has some very useful links, and explains how to approach looping situation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your code is running in the [Swing Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), which means that *everything* you're doing has to finish before it goes back to doing things like responding to button-clicks and drawing changes.

I suggest you look into:

- [`javax.swing.SwingWorker<T,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) as a way to launch complex or time-consuming tasks
- [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) as a way to regularly recalculate and step your simulation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you should really look into Threads and Synchronization.

Threads allow you to do multiple things simultaneously, without having loops and what not holding up your code. It's an important aspect to programming applications that require to do multiple tasks at once. You can learn about threads [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Synchronization keeps consistency, and ensures that multiple Threads manipulating the same data (variables, objects, ect..) will calculate properly. You can learn about Synchronization [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Thread's take a few parameters, but the most important would be `Runnable`. Your `Runnable` will hold the code you want the thread to run. You pass the Runnable to the object. There are multiple ways of doing it, but the two simplest ways to create a Thread that contains a Runnable are:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //your code here
    }
}

Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
```

and a more common way of doing it:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

Now that, hopefully, you have a little better understanding on Threads (I highly recommend reading Oracle's trial for full detail), we can get to what you wanna do.

You wanna calculate code, in which between each calculation, you want a 1 second delay. This is where the `Thread.sleep()` method comes in.

`Thread.sleep()` allows you to pause a thread for a certain amount of time. Seeing how you wanna do it inbetween each calculation, you wanna put it right at the end of your actual code (since it will be in a loop).

```
boolean running;

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            //calculation code

            Thread.sleep(1000); //counted in miliseconds
        }
    }
});
```

Now, as I mentioned before, if you wanna manipulate your UI outside of the class containing the UI, you will have to use `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater()` in order to trigger code in the UIThread, but outside of the class. This method also take a Runnable as a parameter.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //code to manipulate frame/panel/applet
    }
});
```

BTW, Runnable is considered a *functional interface*. *Functional interfaces* are interfaces that only contain one method. That is some information that (from what I see) isnt listed in the Interface trial, which is why I'm letting you know the term now. You can look into interfaces [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

---

```
boolean play = false;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if
    play = !play;

    if(play) {
        if(!thread.isAlive())
            thread.start();
    } else {
        if(thread.isAlive()) {
            thread.interrupt();
            try { thread.join(); }catch(InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so if i understand this correctly i should put 
    

else{if (e.getSource()==playButton) {
      play = true;
      for (int p=0; p<3;p++) {

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){ 
            cells[i%10][i/10].calculateNextState(); 
        }
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){  
            cells[i%10][i/10].updateToNextState();
        }

    }

    }
in my runable (which should be a separate class??) but after this i am kinda lost how and what should i put into my swingUtilities from the original code

Comment: No, Your button should check to see if the thread is alive or not. If it isn't, then `play = true;` and `threadName.start()`. Else, if it's not alive, `play = false;` and `threadName.interrupt()/threadName.join()` (Look into how to stop threads). Also, a little tip for buttons like you're using, `play = !play;` would make the button a stop and start button. Then, write conditions to see what the boolean is set to. There are many different ways to write code.

Comment: sorry but i really new to threads and have a difficult time understanding them. But what you are saying is i should make a different class for thread where i use youy first given code, then is should ask in the action listener where if the play button is pressed the only two things i have to write there is play= true; and thread.start()?

Comment: You can put the thread in the same class as your UI, its up to you. I know reading is a horrid thing to most people, but you should really check out the link to the Thread tutorial, and see what they are. I'm not gonna write an entire code on how to create Threads, seeing how linking you to the page where you can learn about what you need to fix your problem, and also wrote out a thread for you and the placement of your sleep method. You gotta put some effort into it buddy :P For the listener, you need conditions. I'll update my post with what your listener should look like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help i will look into the Thread examples you have given me

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to put Thread.sleep(1000) inside loop to make progress visible AND update the UI ONLY using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). This is not a very beautiful solution, but should work.